# Disable python's help() from accessing web

Tags: python

I am using Python2.7. When I enter help(), and enter "modules", I get the message

```
>>> help()
Welcome to Python 2.7! This is the online help utility.
...
help> modules
Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...
```

Then I get a series of warnings

```
Warning: cannot register existing type 'GtkWidget'
...
Warning: cannot add class private field to invalid type '<invalid>'
...
```

Then the whole thing hangs... to the point where I had to start a second remote session to send a SIGKILL.

obviously something is wrong, but what I was most surprised by was the bit where it reaches out to the web to gather information.

Isn't Python's help documentation available stored locally? How do I stop it from going out to the web? I want regular help, *not online help*.

Comment: It says "this is the online help utility". It's possible that's _always_ been there and somehow I've never noticed it before?

Comment: Whoops, sorry, accidentally deleted my comment while trying to fix an erorr. "Online help" means *it's not printed on paper.*

Comment: On linux you can install python-docs package and look documentation at /usr/share/doc

Comment: export PYTHONDOCS=/usr/share/doc/python2/html/ to determine where python should search help

Comment: I'm pretty sure "all available modules" means the modules that are installed on your system, not all the modules available on the internet. Surely its just trying to import every module on your system and find its documentation?

Comment: Why do you think it's accessing the internet, and not that something in your site-packages causes it to hang? "Online help" is a common phrase used to describe a digitized help system -- it doesn't mean "on the web"..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`help()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#help) command does *not* search on the internet; the "online" simply means that you can use it interactively, in the documentation it calls it "built-in help system" which is less amiguous. What it does it traverses all the `PYTHONPATH` and tries to import every module in order to see which are the available modules in your system.

Here's the source code that is used to obtain the list of module(you can find in under `Lib/pydoc.py` in the python sources):

```
    def listmodules(self, key=''):
        if key:
            self.output.write('''
Here is a list of matching modules.  Enter any module name to get more help.

''')
            apropos(key)
        else:
            self.output.write('''
Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

''')
            modules = {}
            def callback(path, modname, desc, modules=modules):
                if modname and modname[-9:] == '.__init__':
                    modname = modname[:-9] + ' (package)'
                if modname.find('.') < 0:
                    modules[modname] = 1
            def onerror(modname):
                callback(None, modname, None)
            ModuleScanner().run(callback, onerror=onerror)
            self.list(modules.keys())
            self.output.write('''
Enter any module name to get more help.  Or, type "modules spam" to search
for modules whose descriptions contain the word "spam".
''')
```

Where the `ModuleScanner` class simply traverses built-in modules, and the modules that `pkgutil.walk_packages` finds, this function in the ends calls the `iter_modules` method of the importer objects. The built-in importer does *not* support importing modules from the internet, hence the internet is not searched. If you install custom importers than `help()` *may* trigger an internet research.

If you have a lot of modules available then this operation may take some time. Some modules may also take significant time to import(e.g. `numpy`, `scipy` etc may take in the order of seconds to load).

Answer (score 0):

On console `export PYTHONDOCS=/usr/share/doc/python2/html/` to determine where python should search help.